# How to create a struct in Matlab with parts of anothers structs?

Tags: matlab, struct, structure

I have several struct of different dimensions in Matlab. Let us suppose that they were 5, the first is `1x100`, the second `1x250`, the third `1x200`, the fourth `1x100`, and the fifth `1x150`. I want to assemble a new structure containing only the last element of the each previous structures, that is, I want to get a struct of the `1x5` form. How can I do this?

Comment: Using `end` and a simple loop doesn't do the trick? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do all those structs share the same format (i.e. same fields)? Don't you actually have arrays of structs which you want to concatenate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 5 row vectors, then make a row vector from the last elements like this:

```
>> a=[1:100];
>> b=[1:250];
>> c=[1:200];
>> d=[1:100];
>> e=[1:150];
>> the_lasts = [a(end), b(end), c(end), d(end), e(end)]
sthe_last =

   100   250   200   100   150

>>
```

That also can be generalized into a function, using a file named:

ends_of.m :

```
function lasts = ends_of (varargin)
  % prepare a result row vector with nargin dimention
  lasts = zeros(1,nargin);
  for i = 1:nargin
    element = varargin(i); % get the arg
    last = element{}(end); % find the last element
    lasts(i) = last;       % save it as index i 
  endfor
endfunction
```

Then it can be called like this :

```
>> ends_of ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1:44], [3:33], [1,2,3,2,1])
ans =

    3    6   44   33    1

>>
```

Comment: @cris, thanks. i update the answer